# Creating a SharePoint 2013 Discussion Item Using RESTful API

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, listitem

We have a Discussion Board called "Team Discussion"
I am trying to create a Discussion Board Item using the SharePoint 2013 Restful API.
I can successfully create the Discussion Board Item using following,

**Url to which i am posting (url contains the guid for "Team Discussion" Discussion List**

```
http://OurDomain/sites/99812/40242/23653/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c29cef95-6450-4433-8ac8-72d46c9a7fe7')/Items
```

**Headers**

accept: application/json;odata=verbose
X-RequestDigest: 0x98B316961381BB37DD23B8A1F62EAF853584F74F4307744280198682E0B76AB9446D4480FD01F1E27C0AC9DD412BACA2992F0542D49CD1B009CC211BE94DBDCD,31 Jul 2014 02:13:14 -0000
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose

**Body**

{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Team_x0020_DiscussionItem' },  'Title': 'My Team Discussion Item' }

However the programatically created Discussion Board Item doesn't look same as manually created ones. When i go to discussion item, the title is displayed like "Team Discussion  : 47_.000"

It seems like i am not setting the correct meta data for SharePoint to create it correctly.
I even tried to create a List resource instead of a list item and setting BaseTemplate to 108 and BaseType to value 3. It still creates the Discussion item with the same issue.
I also found out that a similar issue exists unless if you use SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussion to create discussion items using Server API.

Any help will be greatly appreciated on how to correct this issue whe using the Resftul API

Regards

Nuwan

Comment: hey hi..hv you get solution for get All replies of Questions .??

Answer (score 0):

It occurs since you are creating a discussion item via `SP.ListItemCollection` resource endpoint. Discussion item in fact is a `SP.Folder` resource and in that case `SP.Folder.Name` is assigned to value `<Id>.000`.

The below example demonstrates how to create a discussion item properly:

```
var listTitle = "Discussions";
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var payload = {
   '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.DiscussionsListItem" },  
   'Title': "Discussion 123",  
   'FileSystemObjectType': 1
};


createNewDiscussion(webUrl,listTitle,payload)
.done(function(item)
{
    console.log('Discussion has been created');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function executeJson(options) 
{
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    var method = options.method || "GET";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: options.url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if("data" in options) {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}


function createListItem(webUrl,listTitle,payload){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
        "method": 'POST',
        "data": payload
    });
}


function fixDiscussionFolder(webUrl,listTitle,payload){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + payload.Id + ")";
    var payload = {
       '__metadata': payload.__metadata,  
       'FileLeafRef' : payload.Title,
    };
    return executeJson({
        'url' :url,
        'headers': {
            'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
            'If-Match': '*'
        },
        'method': "POST",
        'data': payload
    });
}
```

Comment: While this appears to work (the reply shows up in the discussion thread of the parent post) it does not set the `ParentItemID` property on the reply, it remains `null` which breaks some of the features of discussions. See this article: [REST api support for discussion list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/d4de96cc-53eb-4579-a7d4-97e575b08620/rest-api-support-for-new-discussion-list-in-community-site-of-sharepoint-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint)